# Using $resource data to make quick API call

Tags: angularjs

From the Angular Documentation:

```
var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
       // GET: /user/123/card
       // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];

       var card = cards[0];
       // each item is an instance of CreditCard
       expect(card instanceof CreditCard).toEqual(true);
       card.name = "J. Smith";
       // non GET methods are mapped onto the instances
       card.$save();
       // POST: /user/123/card/456 {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
       // server returns: {id:456, number:'1234', name: 'J. Smith'};

       // our custom method is mapped as well.
       card.$charge({amount:9.99});
       // POST: /user/123/card/456?amount=9.99&charge=true {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
     });
```

The above code uses a GET request to get an array of `CreditCard` from the server and then uses $resource class methods like `$save()` or `$delete()` to automagically make API calls back to the server. However, I am running into two problems

**Problem 1**

The `cards` variable expects an array from the server and somehow each `card in cards` can be treated like a `$resource` and use the above methods to make API calls. But our API responses are always of the format:

```
{
  success: true,
  error: null,
  status: 1,
  result: [] // THIS IS THE ACTUAL RESULT
}
```

Where result is the actual data, or in this case the `cards` array. Therefore, running the same code using our API response would not POST the correct data when running something like `card.$save()`

**Problem 2**

I am curious if it is possible (and maybe this is already supported automatically) to have the objects that are bound to the DOM using `ng-repeat` treated exactly like the objects created after a `$resource` call.

For example, lets say I have the same `CreditCards.query()` API call that gets an array of cards and then sets them to a `$scope.cards` variable in the controller. Then I have `ng-repeat="card in cards"` in my DOM to display all of the cards. On each `card` in the DOM I also want to attach an `ng-click="deleteCard(card)"` which will delete the appropriate card from the `$scope.cards` array **as well as send a DELETE request to the server using that specific card as the body in the request**

So the `deleteCard()` function would potentially look like this:

```
$scope.deleteCard = function(card) {

    // REMOVE card from the local array
    var index = $scope.cards.indexOf(card);
    if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
    }

    // REMOVE card from the SERVER
    card.$delete() // Will this work?

}
```

Is this functionality available to us? My guess is Angular would have allowed this to happen

Answer (score 0):

**Problem #1:**

When you use `$resource` you can override the existing methods and/or add new ones so that it will work with your server API.

You will want to do something like this:

```
function transformQueryResponse(data) {
  return JSON.parse(data).result;
}

$resource('/cards/:card_id', {id: '@id'}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false, transformResponse: transformQueryResponse }
});
```

They give an example of creating a custom PUT request at the bottom of the [documentation for $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource).

**Problem #2:**

Yes, you can do this. When you get back $resource objects from the server, they will continue to behave as resources when you use them in an `ng-repeat`.